# In java, how do I convert SQL Spatial Data polygon in text form to a PolgonOptions Object?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, geospatial, spatial

From a webservice, i aquire a polygon in string format, like this:

```
POLYGON ((20.073517049032215 30.063606371213439, ... ,20.073517049032215 30.063606371213439))
```

I want to access all the lat lng points within it, and draw it on a GoogleMap in Android, like this:

```
       map.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(20.073517049032215, 30.063606371213439), ... ,new LatLng(53.558, 9.927))
```

I mean i could iterate through the string somehow and sort all the LatLng objects into an array, but is there a "cleaner" way to achieve this?

Comment: Can I assume you are not in control of the webservice and therefore cannot alter it's output to send you an array or arrays of coordinates?  If not, you're going to have to do it as you think you are - breaking the WKT into an array, and looping through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else who might need this, here is a dodgy workaround. I will try to change the webservice though.

```
        ArrayList<LatLng> polylist = new ArrayList<>();

        String[] parts = news.getArea().replace("POLYGON ((","").replace("))","").split("(?<!\\\\), ");

        for(String part : parts){
            String[] subpart = part.split(" ");
            polylist.add(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(subpart[1]), Double.parseDouble(subpart[0])));
        }

        PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();

        for(LatLng latLng : polylist){
            polygonOptions.add(latLng);         
        }          

        map.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
```